# Is there a Java parser that can parse addresses like this

Tags: java, parsing, street-address

I'm using Java 6.  I'm looking for an automated way to parse addresses.  I'm not concerned if the addresses exist or not.  The best thing I have found is JGeocoder (v 0.4.1), but JGeocoder is unable to parse addresses like this

```
16th Street Theater, Berwyn Cultural Center,  6420 16th St.
```

Does anyone know of a free Java address parser that is up to the challenge?  By "parse" I mean the ability to distinguish street, city, state, postal code, and potentially the venue name (the above venue name is "16th Street Theater, Berwyn Cultural Center").

Comment: Good luck. This is a well-known _extremely_ difficult problem, mostly because of the infinite variety in address formatting.  Having done a lot of this type of work back in the '80s I can guarantee that no perfect (or even 99% perfect) solution exists.  You need different parsing rules for different countries, and even for regions within a country, and a large dictionary of exceptions.  If you're limited to US address, the US Postal Service website may be of help.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** This topic is more exhaustively covered in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-into-components).

---

I work for [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we parse and process addresses, and we have an answer. This is what we call "[SLAP](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/jQuery/slap.html)" or [Single-Line Address Parsing (or Processing)](https://smartystreets.com/archive/parse-and-verify-freeform-street-addresses). The formal term is [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition).

I'm not an expert on Java libraries, but I do know that any in-house implementations will not live up to expectations. Here's some common reasons that people who I've helped have previously had difficulty:

- Google / Yahoo! / Bing Maps web services do not allow automated queries and do not verify accuracy of the parsed address.
- In-house code can make also only make a best guess without any knowledge of existent addresses (a database) or other sorts of official sources. I know you want a library that can do this in-house, but you can at best make a guess...
- By the way, regular expressions are *not* the answer. The best regex I've seen to parse addresses was dynamically generated over hundreds of lines of code and several classes. It was a mess, and was only correct for types of addresses you'd *expect*, not all the valid (US) formats there actually are.

This is an incredibly complex task... unless you have the right tools. One of our services is called [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api), and it's similar to Google Maps in that it parses addresses and geocodes them, but goes a step further by being CASS-Certified and returning only *valid* addresses, almost no matter the input format.

I encourage you to do some research of your own, but this is probably the most effective and reliable method.

Comment: As I feared, this service isn't free.  I'm not marking this as correct only b/c I did specify I was looking for something free.  However, maybe you'll get some good promotion as people find this answer through Google.

Comment: Actually it is free; it only costs money if you choose a higher query limit than the default 250/mo. But of course, you should find something to meet your needs. Let us know what you decide if you do find something else!

Answer (score 3):

https://code.google.com/p/usaddressparser/ Parses US address string and splits it into fields ( number, street, suite,city,zip etc.). Java jar and sources

Comment: it appears this project page was created and a single line of code was never written

Comment: actually, there is code, it's just buried in a zip file

Answer (score 0):

If webservices are allowed, you could try google maps.

Comment: The TOS does not allow automated queries.